# How to middle align text in a list item if the previous list item is heigher than it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do you middle align text in a list item if the previous list item is heigher than it?

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li style="background-color: aqua;">
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;background-color:green;display:block;">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-color: lime;">
        <div style="height:50px;background-color:green;display:block;">Brendan</div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-color: salmon;">Vogt</li>
</ul>
```

I am using `Bootstrap`. The first list item has to have a height and width of 50px. It is meant to be used for a colour. The second list item is plain text. The text is 10px in height.

I tried adding padding in the `<li></li>` but it doesn't work. I tried adding margin but this also doesn't work. I've tried adding the same to the `<div></div>` surrounding the text, also nothing happens. Seems like the padding and margin is added but overlaps the other elements so it looks like nothing happens.

How do I middle align the text?

PS: The styling is inline at the moment as I am playing around with it, will move it to an external style sheet later when everything works.

Comment: http://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/xGNeMe Expecting something like this ???

Comment: @krish Your code doesn't display correctly at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li style="background-color: green;">
      <div style="padding: 15px 23px;background-color: aqua;">&nbsp;</div>
   </li>
   <li style="background-color: green;">
      <div style="padding: 15px 0 15px 0;background-color: lime;">Brendan</div>
   </li>
   <li style="background-color: green;">
      <div style="padding: 15px 0 15px 0;background-color: yellow;">Vogt</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I needed the first colour block 50px high and wide. The `&nbsp;` is 4px wide and 20px high, hence the `padding: 15px 23px;`. The text in the other list items I'm not too worried about the length because the text can be varying length. I just set the hight. The text is 20px high hence the `padding: 15px 0 15px 0;`.

I'm not a CSS expert but this works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this ..

```
.list-inline > li div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 14px;
}
```

here is the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/agj9z1wy/1/).

Comment: Explain to me why you have these values?

Answer (score 1):

Use the css property inline-css for li it will work for you

```
<li style="text-align: center !Important;"
   </li>
```

Or use line-height property

Comment: I'm not with you on this, can you maybe show some more code?

Answer (score 1):

If you need vertical alignment you can use `display: table-cell` property. Since you already have `ul` and `li` they can be table and table-rows accordingly. In this case `ul li > div` would be table-cells which allow to use `vertical-align: middle`. You can additionally set `text-align: center` If needed.

```css
.list-inline {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-inline li {
    display: table-row;
}
.list-inline li > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
.list-inline li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: aqua;
}
.list-inline li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lime;
}
.list-inline li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: salmon;
}
.myColor {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <div>
      <div class="myColor"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Brendan</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Vogt</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @BrendanVogt what's your browser?

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of Chrome

Comment: @BrendanVogt can you please attach an image of what you've got by running my snippet and an image of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all list items to appear in one row and to be vertically align center to each other?

If I understood your question correctly then this should help you -

`<ul class="list-inline">
    <li style="background-color: aqua; height:50px; width:50px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"> &nbsp; </li>
    <li style="background-color: lime; display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"> Brendan </li>
    <li style="background-color: salmon; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"> Vogt </li>
</ul>`